# firefox javascript return false in href redirects the browser and displays false

Tags: javascript, firefox

following is my code working well in chrome.

```
<body>

<a href="javascript: sam.save();">hehe</a>

<script>

var sam = {
    save : function()
    {
        alert("here")
            return false;       
    }
}
</script>
```

when in run in firefox the page redirects and false is displayed on the screen with the adress bar content like in the picture

[image]

firefox version is 9.0.1

suggestions and circumvents please...

Comment: I tested the code, and it works in the latest version of Firefox. It's 13.0, so you are a bit behind...

Comment: after clicking the link in the code it redirects to like in the screen shot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code you cite can't possibly produce the behavior you observe.  The observed behavior would only happen if `sam.save()` returned `false`, whereas the quoted code returns `undefined`.  What does your actual complete code look like?

**Edit:** The useful answer was in a comment. I put it here to make it easier to find.

> Oh, I missed the "return false" after the alert. In that case, the behavior you see is correct: if the javascript: execution returns a value other than undefined that value is treated as a string of HTML and rendered. At least in most browsers. – Boris Zbarsky Jun 11 at 15:25

Comment: the complete code is what i have given... as you have said if there is return false then the result is in the screen shot... if there is no return false then every thing works fine ...

Comment: Oh, I missed the "return false" after the alert.  In that case, the behavior you see is correct: if the javascript: execution returns a value other than `undefined` that value is treated as a string of HTML and rendered.  At least in most browsers.

Answer (score 9):

For some reason return false doesn't work in FF inside href="javascript:", but void(0) does.

```
<a href="javascript: sam.save();void(0);">hehe</a>
```

Comment: This saved me some headaches. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
<a href="#" onclick="sam.save();">hehe</a>
```

Comment: i had been using this... after a bit discrepancies previously i did it like in the code.

Answer (score 2):

The more compatible syntax should be

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="sam.save()">hehe</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
`<a href="javascript: void(sam.save())">hehe</a>`
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Example how it works:

Firefox: Second and third is rendering a white page

Chromium: The first case is rendering the white page

```
<body>

<a href="javascript: something.with_early_return();">with_early_return</a>
<a href="javascript: something.with_false();">with_false</a>
<a href="javascript: something.with_string();">with_string</a>

<script>

var something = {
    with_early_return: function() {
        alert("with_early_return");
        return;
    },

    with_false: function () {
        alert('with_false');
        return false;
    },

    with_string: function () {
        alert('with_string');
        return 'It renders this as text';
    }
}
</script>
```